# Youtube embed video doesn't play in Xiaomi device Cordova WebView

Tags: android, cordova, youtube

I have a strange behaviour in a cordova app with a page containing a video from youtube:

`<iframe width="100%" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bTqVqk7FSmY?feature=player_embedded&showinfo=0&rel=0" allow="accelerometer; gyroscope; magnetometer; autoplay; encrypted-media" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

It works on ios & android simulators, but fail on my device : Xiaomi MiA1.

I tested it on a Samsung device and it works too.

Here is my config.xml for testing:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
                        default-src * data: blob: ws: wss: gap://ready file://*;
                        style-src * 'unsafe-inline';
                        script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
                        connect-src * ws: wss:;">
```

And this error when i try to play :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hide' of null
at E_.J (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:7383:299)
at new E_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:4105:292)
at new M_ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:4142:493)
at g.O_.init (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:7424:39)
at lY.g.h.fy (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:7013:69)
at new g0 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:4217:223)
at https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-vflT6zTz3/fr_FR/base.js:7566:161
at Jh.Mh.a.w (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflo0Y8an/www-embed-player.js:502:261)
at Mh (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflo0Y8an/www-embed-player.js:503:12)
at Jh.k.ga (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vflo0Y8an/www-embed-player.js:498:4)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'l' of undefined
at M_.g.h.Sn (VM41 base.js:7415)
at sra (VM41 base.js:3874)
at M_.g.h.nT (VM41 base.js:7122)
```

Comment: I believe this has to do with the webview version you are running on the device